# Getting a TypeError error on console with an Ajax script

Tags: javascript, debugging, typeerror

I have a problem with my for loop in ajax. I'm using this script to GET a list of images through an API:

```
let request = new new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        let img = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        for(let i = 0; i < img.totalHits; i++) {
            $('#media').append(' <img src=" '+ img.hits[i].previewURL +' "> ');
        }
    }

};

request.open('GET', 'https://pixabay.com/api/key=************&per_page=100&image_type=' + image_type + '', true);

request.send();
```

When I go to Firefox Developer Edition console I have this problem:

[image: Firefox Developer Edition screenshot.]

When I go to google console I have this error:

[image: Google screenshot.]

I tried to fix without any result. Do you think it's a normal error when I use ajax?

Comment: Change `<=` to `<`. Array indexes go from 0 to length-1.

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I've changed the text.
Als I tried to do as you said but I have the same error.

Comment: What does `console.log(img.totalHits, img.hits.length);` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `img.hits.length` instead of `img.totalHits`. `totalHits` is the total number of hits available, not the number returned by this call, which is limited by the `per_page=100` parameter.

In your code, when `i >= 100`, you're trying to access outside the `img.hits` array, so `img.hits[i]` is `undefined` and you get an error trying to access its property.

You can call the API repeatedly with increasing values of the `page` parameter to get successive pages of results, until you get all `totalHits` results.

Comment: I changed them but I have the same problem.
console.log(img.totalHits, img.hits.length);
  show two variables: 500 100

Comment: Anyway, the script works without any problem. I'm just curious to know about that problem.

Comment: Ok perfect, I've updated  `i <= img.hits.length` with `i <= 99` and i don't have anymore that error. Thank's for the explanation!

Comment: That's wrong, it will get an error on the last page since there won't be 100 images.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `i < img.hits.length`, it should work perfectly.